# InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits

Tags: android, image, exception, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted image in Android using this code:

```
public class SimpleCryptoActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
            // get the encrypted image from assets folder
            InputStream is = am.open("2000_1.jpg_encrypted");

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];  

            int read;
            //convert inputstream to bytearrayoutputstream
            while ((read = is.read(b)) != -1) {  
                baos.write(b, 0, read);
            }   
            byte[] key = "MARTIN_123_MARTIN_123".getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] iv = "1234567890123456".getBytes("UTF-8");

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L; // start
            byte[] decryptedData = decrypt(key, iv, b);

            //END
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;    // end
            Log.d("TEST","Time start "+ String.valueOf(start));
            Log.d("TEST","Time end "+ String.valueOf(end));

            //decoding bytearrayoutputstream to bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = 
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decryptedData,
                                              0,
                                              decryptedData.length);    

            int i = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight() ;

            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            is.close(); // close the inputstream
            baos.close(); // close the bytearrayoutputstream
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
            Log.e("error","err",e);
        }
    } 

    //decrypt
    private byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] iv, byte[] encrypted)
            throws Exception {

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);         
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

and the exception is:

```
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104): err
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104): java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at com.cryptooo.lol.SimpleCryptoActivity.onCreate(SimpleCryptoActivity.java:62)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-27 09:01:53.162: ERROR/error(3104):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestions how to fix that?

PHP code:

```
$files = array(
        '007FRAMESUPERIOR.jpg',
        '2000_1.jpg',
        'APLICACIONdescargaliga.jpg',
        'APPCOMMENTS.pdf',
        'AUDIOVISUALFOTO02.jpg'
        );
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = "1234567890123456";
        $key = "MARTIN_123_MARTIN_123";
foreach($files as $file)
{
            $input_file = $folder . $file;
$text = file_get_contents($input_file);
            //$text = "Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument.";
            echo strlen($text) . "\n";
function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 16){
    $len = strlen($string);
    $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
    $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    return $string;
}


$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, addpadding($text), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Comment: The documentation for `mcrypt_encrypt` says what it will do with short keys, not what it does with overlong ones. I suspect it just truncates them. The PHP code is also somewhat flawed in that it measures the IV size for `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`, but then uses `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` (it doesn't matter in this case because they're the same length, but that's not generally true for cipher suites)

Comment: That's my mistake in the PHP code sry.As a matter of fact that code is not for an application.It's just for testing AES encryption/decryption to se the time it takes to encrypt/decrypt image on real device.That's why I need to finish this.It's making me crazy two days now,because I'm really new in Android programming and ecnryption/decryption methods.

Comment: @hardartcore could you update your fixed code? php and java?

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy I no longer have access to that code and can't do that, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alex already mentioned, Password-Based Encryption is the way to go for you. AES keys need to be exactly 128, 192 or 256 bits long. So passwords of arbitrary length won't work in your situation right away, but using a "normal" password of the right size is also wrong, because these kinds of passwords do not contain enough entropy and will allow attackers to brute-force them more easily because they are not random enough.

---

With that said, let's take a look at your implementation. Instead of taking a String as a password in PHP what you should probably do is generate 16 bytes (128 bit) with Java's `SecureRandom' class or anything equivalent in PHP (don't know if such a thing is available, remember it needs to be a cryptographically secure random number). Encode that using Base64 so that you obtain a String representation of the key to be used both in Java and PHP.

Do the same for an IV that is exactly 16 bytes long (always the same as AES block size), encode it to Base64 again. You do this not for the reason that it has to be secret or complicated, but for the encoding issues that your approach is almost surely to cause. As far as I know PHP's default encoding is *not* UTF-8, so your approach is doomed to fail.

Using these two values (Base64-decode them before usage!) you're ready to go on the PHP side. In Java, obtain your Cipher using

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PAdding");
```

and initialize it with the same IV and key used in PHP (again remember to Base64-decode first).

**Final note:** I do not recommend what I just described because it means that your keys will be hardcoded into your source files. That is actually not really secure and generally frowned upon. If you want to do symmetric encryption with passwords, then you should use PBE and not store the passwords anywhere, at the very least not in the client code.  Another possibility is involving asymmetric public/private key cryptography, e.g. using a Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: So basically if I want to use AES encryption/decryption I can't do that : byte[] keys = "MARTIN_123_MARTIN_123".getBytes("UTF-8"); ? I need to set the key as you say exactly 128,192,256 bits. So how can I modify my code to use AES decryption of an image? Any ideas

Comment: I added a code sample. Of course this method only works if you do the encryption, too. Otherwise you need to find out exactly what methods were used to encrypt the image.

Comment: I know how the image is encrypted, I will edit the question with the php code

Comment: @psychenaut: I updated my post, the sample was not appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Actually it's just a test application,not to be implemented in real application.I just need to test the speed of AES encryption/decryption on a real device so I can make a decision if it's good for use in my case or I have to find another faster and secure way.For now I just need to see the speed of AES decryption.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use AES with some pass phrase you choose. Encryption when you use your own password is called PBE (password based encryption). AES key must be generated initially to conform to algorithm specs. Take a look at this [article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html). You could apply PBE on top of AES key if needed.

PBE Tutorial can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/PBEFileEncrypt.htm).

Comment: Actually my first version of code was like this :  http://pastebin.com/Kd48f2bV  and I just need to find a way to decrypt the image with the key: MARTIN_123_MARTIN_123  but when I use that code it's thworin an exception : http://pastebin.com/QgLrGgtx

Comment: So you seeded your random with your presumed passphrase. It will just make random generator generate specific sequence. But in the question you are just sending your key as raw value of AES key. Not going to work. Look at PBE, I think that's what you need: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/PBEFileEncrypt.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use only 16 character length in key

Comment: how?? we used 16 character length??